# Square AC to Sinusoidal AC

Tags: filter, ac

Can we convert a an AC supply which outputs a square wave to a sine wave?  Many uninterruptible power supplies (UPSes) produce square waves.  12V adapters can't bear this square wave, but can handle sinusoids.  How is this conversion possible?

Comment: AC is almost always (to not say always) sinewave, and if it's not, a low pass RC filter will suffice.

Comment: `which adapters of 12volts can't bear` That's actually pretty rare. Large number of adapters will in fact work correctly with a square wave.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Several possbilities:

No, "normal" UPSs don't necessarily produce square waves.  Some, particularly old ones, do.  There are three common types: square, modified sine, and sine.  Square wave should be obvious.  Modified sine is trying to get closer to a sine wave while still just switching.  In this case instead of switching between + and - power, it also switches to 0.  The resulting waveform is more sine-like, which is another way of saying it has lower harmonic content.  Then of course the true sine wave inverters put out real sine waves with low harmonic content close to what the power line is.

If square wave power is such a problem, get a UPS that puts out a sine or possibly modified sine.  The premium for sine is much lower than it used to be.

Are you sure your 12 V adapter "can't bear" a square wave?  Most of them would be fine with that.  Just about any universal power input switcher should be fine with a square wave input.  If you really have a power supply that doesn't like square wave in, then get one that does.  The newer supply will probably be lighter and more efficient than the old klunker anyway.

Trying to somehow convert a square wave to a sine wave is not a good idea when this is intended for significant power.  If it were a signal instead of power, it would be easy enough to low pass filter it to reduce the harmonics, then amplify it back up to the right level.  That doesn't work for power because this process has a lot of power loss and you can't amplify the result.  You could try a inductor in series followed by a capacitor accross the signal, but the inductor will be big and expensive to handle significant power and do meaningful filtering.  You didn't say what your power level is, but replacing the old klunker UPS or getting a modern 12 V power supply will probably be cheaper than a very large inductor.  And, with the indutor/capacitor filter, the voltage and harmonic content will be somewhat load dependent.

Comment: Olin, are "true" sine-wave inverters made by PWM? I suppose the question is, is sinusoidal PWM's harmonic content close to a "real" sine wave?

Comment: @Saad: Yes, sine wave inverters are basically switching power supplies, and are also similar to class D amplifiers. They switch at many times the 50 or 60 Hz output frequency. The switching noise is small compared to the power frequency amplitude to begin with, and it is easier to filter due to the high frequency. The total harmonic content is small enough to not matter. Keep in mind the power line has spikes and other noise on it so isn't a perfect sine either.

Answer (score 1):

The answer is clear. Instead of building a device to fix the UPS, just find a better UPS that puts out a sinusoidal wave. (And only if it's obvious that it won't work with some of your devices, and it's not easier/cheaper to just replace those devices or their power supplies.)

Building a hack to solve this is only cheaper if you assume that your time is worth nothing.

The crappy square wave UPS + parts + your time spent researching, acquiring and building quite likely exceed the cost of a nicer UPS.

If you want to build this for fun or to learn, that's a different matter; then those costs are your tuition fee, so to speak.